# Help on Serial print (Arduino C)

Tags: c

```
void loop() {
  photoCell = analogRead(pin);
  time = millis();

if (photoCell >= 400){
timeon = millis();
led = 1;
while (analogRead(pin) >= 400) {
  timer = millis() - timeon;
   //Serial.print("On");
   //Serial.println(timer);

  }
}

if (photoCell <= 400) {
  timeoff = millis(); 
  led = 0;
  while (analogRead(pin) <= 400) {
    timer2 = millis() - timeoff;
    //Serial.print("Off");
    //Serial.println(timer2);

  }
}

 if (timer >= 175 && timer <= 200 && led == 1) {
    Serial.print("Char = ");
    Serial.println(".");
    codearray[i] = 8;
    i++;
  }
  if (timer >= 580 && timer <= 600 && led == 1) {
    Serial.print("Char = ");
    Serial.println("-");
    codearray[i] = 9;
    i++;
  }
```

This is my current code which works fine using a photocell plugged into A0 and an led wired into pin 9. The serial monitor displays whether or not I am flashing a dot or dash, morse corde, based on the timing.

However.. When I add this bit of code

```
if (codearray[0] == 8 && codearray[1] == 8 && 
codearray[2] == 8 && codearray[3] == 0) {
  Serial.print("s");
}
```

The monitor prints nothing. This bit of code fills out an array I set up so I can print back into alphabetical the morse code that was deciphered. I'm pretty sure my logic is correct.

Looking to see if anyone understands why the 2nd bit of code would conflict with the first or what can be wrong with the analog input or serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is off topic here; probably belongs on stack overflow.

But it is obvious that you forgot to call Serial.Begin(9600); in setup(); n.b. 9600 is the arduino default baud rate.